# Form choice direct to webpage

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Hi I am trying to get a form to route to a specified webpage based on chosen options. I have seen some answers on a previous thread by https://stackoverflow.com/users/726326/dentaku but can't get it to work i've probably missed something simple. many thanks in advance

```
<!---
<form>
<p> Type of Purchase: </p>

<select id="type">
<option value="0" id="Select">Select</option>
<option value="1" id="vaccation_rental">Vaccation Rental</option>
<option value="2" id="purchase">Purchase</option>
<option value="3" id="rental">Long Term Rental</option>
</select>

<p>Type of Property</p>
<select id="property">
<option value="0" id="Select">Select</option>
<option value="1" id="Villa">Villa</option>
<option value="2" id="Cabana">cabana</option>

</select>

<br /><br />

 <input  onclick="goToPage();"  type="button" value="Submit" /> 
 </form>

 <script type="text/javascript">

function goToPage()
{


<script>
var targetURL;
if (type==0) {
switch (property) {
    case 1: targetURL = "http://www.mysite.com/index.html";
    case 2: targetURL = "http://www.mysite.com/index.html";
    case 3: targetURL = "http://www.mysite.com/index.html";
}
} else if (type==1) {
switch (property) {
    case 1: targetURL = "http://www.mysite.com/Rental.html";
    case 2: targetURL = "http://www.mysite.com/VRental_villa.html";
    case 3: targetURL = "http://www.mysite.com/VRental_cabana.html";

}
} else if (type==2) {
switch (property) {
    case 1: targetURL = "http://www.mysite.com/Buying.html";
    case 2: targetURL = "http://www.mysite.com/Buying_villa.html";
    case 2: targetURL = "http://www.mysite.com/Buying_cabana.html";
}
} else {
switch (property) {
    case 1: targetURL = "http://www.mysite.com/Rental.html";
    case 2: targetURL = "http://www.mysite.com/Rental_villa.html";
    case 3: targetURL = "http://www.mysite.com/Rental_cabana.html";
}
}
targetURL ? window.location.href = targetURL : alert("Type of Property.");</script>  
<!-- end .content --></div>
<!-- end .container --></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form>
<p> Type of Purchase: </p>

<select id="type">
<option value="0" id="Select">Select</option>
<option value="1" id="vaccation_rental">Vaccation Rental</option>
<option value="2" id="purchase">Purchase</option>
<option value="3" id="rental">Long Term Rental</option>
</select>

<p>Type of Property</p>
<select id="property">
<option value="0" id="Select">Select</option>
<option value="1" id="Villa">Villa</option>
<option value="2" id="Cabana">cabana</option>

</select>

<br /><br />

 <input  onclick="goToPage();"  type="button" value="Submit" /> 
 </form>

 <script type="text/javascript">

function goToPage()
{

var targetURL;
if (parseInt(type.options[type.selectedIndex].value,10) === 0) {
switch (parseInt(property.options[property.selectedIndex].value,10)) {
    case 0: targetURL = "http://www.mysite.com/index.html"; break;
    case 1: targetURL = "http://www.mysite.com/index.html"; break;
    case 2: targetURL = "http://www.mysite.com/index.html"; break;
}
} else if (parseInt(type.options[type.selectedIndex].value,10) === 1) {
switch (parseInt(property.options[property.selectedIndex].value,10)) {
    case 0: targetURL = "http://www.mysite.com/Rental.html"; break;
    case 1: targetURL = "http://www.mysite.com/VRental_villa.html"; break;
    case 2: targetURL = "http://www.mysite.com/VRental_cabana.html"; break;

}
} else if (parseInt(type.options[type.selectedIndex].value,10) ===2) {
switch (parseInt(property.options[property.selectedIndex].value,10)) {
    case 0: targetURL = "http://www.mysite.com/Buying.html"; break;
    case 1: targetURL = "http://www.mysite.com/Buying_villa.html"; break;
    case 2: targetURL = "http://www.mysite.com/Buying_cabana.html"; break;
}
} else {
switch (parseInt(property.options[property.selectedIndex].value,10)) {
    case 0: targetURL = "http://www.mysite.com/Rental.html"; break;
    case 1: targetURL = "http://www.mysite.com/Rental_villa.html"; break;
    case 2: targetURL = "http://www.mysite.com/Rental_cabana.html"; break;
}
}
alert(targetURL);
//targetURL ? window.location.href = targetURL : alert("Type of Property.");
}
</script>  
<!-- end .content --></div>
<!-- end .container --></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is a working version of your code. The most immediate bits that broke it was the opening `<script>` tag and the lack of a closing bracket for the `goToPage` function. How ever your code was broken on a deeper and far more subtle way.

```
if (type==0) {
switch (property) {
```

Here, `type` and `property` refer to the actual select elements themselves, not the value of the currently selected option, which what you were looking for. To get the selected 
option use

```
SelectElement.options[SelectElement.selectedIndex].value
```

You then have to wrap it in `parseInt` to convert it into a number for comparison. Don't forget to specify a radix so it always converts into a proper base 10 number.

You didn't add any break statements to your cases, so if you matched one the and there is a case under it, that case will be executed as well. Also you started counting at 1 in the script but the values in the options start at 0.

Finally, the most important bit is when you are comparing using 0, use strict equality, the three equal signs(===) to do comaprisions. Why? Because 0 is a falsy, anything that is falsy will evaluate to true using normal equality.

```
0 == false;
true;
0 == [];
true;
```

As a tip, I suggest creating strings with the values instead of all of these switch/case statements. If you wanted to add a boathouse later on you would need to update ever single one which is prone to programmer error and is just a hassle in general.

```
<select id="type">
<option value="" id="Select">Select Type</option>
<option value="rent" id="Select">Rent</option>
</select>

<p>Type of Property</p>
<select id="property">
<option value="" id="Select">Select Property</option>
<option value="boathouse" id="Select">Boathouse</option>

</select>

<br /><br />
    <input  onclick="goToPage();"  type="button" value="Submit" /> 
 </form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function goToPage(){
        var baseURL = 'http://www.mysite.com/'
        var targetURL = window.location.href; // Default value
        if(type.options[type.selectedIndex].value != false && property.options[property.selectedIndex].value != false){
            // If we have both values use them with underscore
            targetURL = baseURL+type.options[type.selectedIndex].value+"_"+property.options[property.selectedIndex].value+'.html';
        }else if(type.options[type.selectedIndex].value || property.options[property.selectedIndex].value){
            // Use whatever one we have
            targetURL = baseURL+ (type.options[type.selectedIndex].value || property.options[property.selectedIndex].value)+'.html';
        }
        alert(targetURL);
    }

</script>
```

I haven't really done much testing on that but it works and can easily be improved but I think it gets the idea across.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `type` and `property` are not defined anywhere in your webpage. You will need to add this at the beginning of your function:

```
var type = document.getElementById("type").value;
var property = document.getElementById("property").value;
```

Also, why did you use `switch` for property and not for type? You can use it for both:

```
    switch (type) {
    case 1:
        switch(property) {
            case 1:
                targetURL = "http://www.mysite.com/index.html";
                break;
            case 2:
                targetURL = "http://www.mysite.com/index.html";
                break;
            case 3:
                targetURL = "http://www.mysite.com/index.html";
                break;
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        switch (property) {
            case 1:
                targetURL = "http://www.mysite.com/Rental.html";
                break;
            case 2:
                targetURL = "http://www.mysite.com/VRental_villa.html";
                break;
            case 3:
                targetURL = "http://www.mysite.com/VRental_cabana.html";
                break;
        }
        break;
    ....
}
```

Finally, I find better, for this kind of page navigation, to change the form's `action` in the `onsubmit` event:

Change HTML to:

```
<form id="myForm" onsubmit=onFormSubmit()>
```

Change JS to:

```
function onFormSubmit() {
    // Getting the dropdown values
    var type = parseInt(document.getElementById("type").value);
    var property = parseInt(document.getElementById("property").value);

    // Setting the URL depending on the type / property
    var targetURL;
    switch (type) {
        case 1:
            switch(property) {
                case 1:
                    targetURL = "http://www.mysite.com/index.html";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    targetURL = "http://www.mysite.com/index.html";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    targetURL = "http://www.mysite.com/index.html";
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            switch (property) {
                case 1:
                    targetURL = "http://www.mysite.com/Rental.html";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    targetURL = "http://www.mysite.com/VRental_villa.html";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    targetURL = "http://www.mysite.com/VRental_cabana.html";
                    break;
            }
            break;
        ....
    }

    // Setting the form's action
    document.getElementById("myForm").action = targetURL;

    // Return true so the submit can continue
    return true;
}
```